# Change format spacing in division equation

Tags: output-formatting

Is there any way to change the formatted spacing of an equation with a division? Something similar to LineSpacing for text formatting, but which makes equations more compact. I'm hoping to not lose the traditional formatting of other parts of the equation.

Hopefully, these two snippets should explain what sort of thing I'm hoping for.

```
TraditionalForm[A/B]
Style["A\n\[LongDash]\nB", LineSpacing -> {0,7}]
```